# OSGi dynamic version for one class

Tags: osgi

I have OSGi bundle in which One service class is used by two clients. both the clients using the same version of service class say 1.0, now i have made some changes in service class and updating the version of service class say 1.1, now my problem is I want both the versions of the service class means one client can use 1.0 version and another client can use 1.1 how can achieve this? If any sample can provide me for dynamic versioning its really helpfull for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of a service is the version of the **interface** it implements, which comes from the version of the exported package that that interface exists in.

The service implementation class version is irrelevant because the consumer of the service has no knowledge of the implementation class. Therefore if you register multiple services with the same interface, they will all be visible to the consumer.

Comment: Actually I get some information on this blog http://blog.webforefront.com/archives/2009/02/osgi_versioning.html regarding versioning. I want to such type of functionality in my sample application. But I don't understand how to implement that functionality please help me to develop such type functionality for my project POC. Sample Application would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think OSGi has a real notion of service versions, but you can use any key/value pair you like when registering a service. The [Knopflerfish tutorial](http://www.knopflerfish.org/osgi_service_tutorial.html) is pretty good I think.

For example, when registering a service:

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.put("version", "1.0");
bundleContext.registerService(ServiceInterface.class.getName(), impl, props);
```

Then, when consuming a service, you can use those attributes to require certain attributes.

Having multiple versions of this service is very easy, the tricky part is how the service consumers deal with it.

If you have two consumers using version 1.0, and 1.1 appears (for example when a new bundle has been started), should the consumers stop using 1.0 and start using 1.1? In your example, one of the consumers should ignore this, while the other should rewire to 1.1. This gets especially complicated when one consumer consumes multiple services.

I recommend looking into Declarative services, it can make this a lot easier and keep your code cleaner, I'd say [start here](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Declarative_Services)